# How to define different priors for $\mu$ parameters using a Normal-Inverse-Wishart prior?

Tags: multivariate-normal-distribution, conjugate-prior

Suppose,

$y_i \sim N_2 (\mu, \Sigma)$

I want to define a Normal-Inverse-Wishart prior on $\mu$ and $\Sigma$. Such that,

$(\mu, \Sigma) \sim NIW(\mu_0,\lambda,\Psi,v)$

My prior knowledge about $\mu = \{\mu_1,\mu_2\}$ is:

$\mu_1 \sim Normal(1,0.02)$ ,

$\mu_2 \sim Normal(1,100)$

**Is there any way to express these priors for $\mu$ in the Normal-Inverse-Wishart prior?**

Note: I have tried adjusting values of $\lambda$ parameter. It is possible to achieve almost the same prior for one of the $\{\mu_1,\mu_2\}$, but not for both of them at the same time.

Comment: Rigorously, since the [marginal distribution of $\mu$ is a multivariate $t$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal-Wishart_distribution#Marginal_distributions), the prior information on $\mu$ is not compatible with the Norma-Inverse-Wishart.